# Java debugging issue

Tags: java, debugging

```
class Celsius {
    public static void main(String[] args){
      celsius(0);
    }
    public static void celsius(double fahrenheitTemperature){
        double celsiusTemperature;
        for (fahrenheitTemperature = 0; fahrenheitTemperature <= 20; fahrenheitTemperature++) {
            celsiusTemperature = ((fahrenheitTemperature - 32) * 5) / 9;
            double celsius_rounded = Math.round(celsiusTemperature * 100)/100.0;
            System.out.println("Fahrenheit: " + fahrenheitTemperature + "  Celsius: " + celsius_rounded);


         }
        }
    }
```

The code runs fine. The problem is when I call the method, whatever parameter I give, I am getting the same result. If I put 20 or 0 in the parameter of the celsius method, I will get these same results.

What can I do to debug this issue?

My result:

```
Fahrenheit: 0.0  Celsius: -17.78
Fahrenheit: 1.0  Celsius: -17.22
Fahrenheit: 2.0  Celsius: -16.67
Fahrenheit: 3.0  Celsius: -16.11
Fahrenheit: 4.0  Celsius: -15.56
Fahrenheit: 5.0  Celsius: -15.0
Fahrenheit: 6.0  Celsius: -14.44
Fahrenheit: 7.0  Celsius: -13.89
Fahrenheit: 8.0  Celsius: -13.33
Fahrenheit: 9.0  Celsius: -12.78
Fahrenheit: 10.0  Celsius: -12.22
Fahrenheit: 11.0  Celsius: -11.67
Fahrenheit: 12.0  Celsius: -11.11
Fahrenheit: 13.0  Celsius: -10.56
Fahrenheit: 14.0  Celsius: -10.0
Fahrenheit: 15.0  Celsius: -9.44
Fahrenheit: 16.0  Celsius: -8.89
Fahrenheit: 17.0  Celsius: -8.33
Fahrenheit: 18.0  Celsius: -7.78
Fahrenheit: 19.0  Celsius: -7.22
Fahrenheit: 20.0  Celsius: -6.67
```

Comment: you are initializing fahrenheitTemperature everytime with 0 in the method for loop that's why. :)

Comment: Value in the fahrenheitTemperature variable always update the values inside the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your 'FOR' loop initialises fahrenheitTemperature=0, thereby overwriting whatever value you passed in. A solution may be as follow:

```
for(dobule i = fahrenheitTemperature; i<=20;i++){
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the for loop:

```
 for (fahrenheitTemperature = 0; fahrenheitTemperature <= 20; fahrenheitTemperature++)
```

whatever value you pass to the method, you put this value to 0 at the beginning of the for loop.

Change your code with something like this:

```
public class Celsius {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        celsius(0);
        celsius(0, 20);
    }

    public static void celsius(double fahrenheitTemperature) {
        double celsiusTemperature = ((fahrenheitTemperature - 32) * 5) / 9;
        double celsius_rounded = Math.round(celsiusTemperature * 100) / 100.0;
        System.out.println("Fahrenheit: " + fahrenheitTemperature + "  Celsius: " + celsius_rounded);

    }

    public static void celsius(double start, double end) {
        for (double fahrenheitTemperature = start; fahrenheitTemperature <= end; fahrenheitTemperature++) {
            celsius(fahrenheitTemperature);

        }
    }
}
```

In this manner you can print single value or more then one.